# Validate values for decimal and integers

Tags: c#, regex, validation

I need to validate that a TextBox contains only numbers, with allowances for commas and/or decimal points.

Here are a few examples of valid entries:

- 12.7
- 19.245,7
- 11,123.326.7
- 16,7
- 0.19
- 0,5

And here are some examples of invalid entries:

- 12.00 --> 12
- 19.000,7 --> 19000,7
- .125 --> 0.125
- 000.000 --> 0

I'm using this regex, both it doesn't work:  `@"^[0-9]([\.\,][0-9]{1,3})?$"`

How can I do this?

Comment: Could you share more light on the context ... it might help simplify the answers

Comment: Trying hard to understand why a "0,5" is valid and a "12.00" is invalid (in your list)

Comment: Please specify ASP.NET or WebForms, as the solutions for each could be quite different.

Comment: Also trying hard to understand why `19.000,7` is invalid while `19.245,7` is valid.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using asp.net. You can use the comparevalidator and set the Operator to DataTypeCheck and set Type to Double (or currency)